# How can I connect my Reactjs Web App to a secured MQTT broker?

Tags: reactjs, mqtt

I have a reactjs web application that needs to connect to a secured mqtt broker.

The web application is deployed in AWS elastic beanstalk and is using HTTPS. I already have a secured MQTT broker but when trying to connect my web app to the mqtt broker I have this error:

**Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

I am using MQTTjs package. I already have certificate for both server and client side.

Here's my code:

```
var client = mqtt.connect('wss://[ipaddress]:8884');
```

I also tried this code:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


var CERT = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './ca.crt'));
var KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './ca.key'));


var options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    port: 8884,
    host: ipaddress,
    protocol: 'mqtts',
    ca: CERT,
    keyPath: KEY,
    certPath: CERT
}
```

But the error for this code is:

**Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load certificates from disk in the browser. So the second version of the code just won't work.

You need to add both the CA and the Client certificate to your browsers certificate store.

The browser should then use the CA cert to validate the broker and should then pick the correct client cert to present to the broker as identification.

Comment: Is there any way we can add the CA and client certificate programmatically? Or is there any way we can connect to a secured MQTT without the certificate?

Comment: Adding certificates to the browser cert store entirely the environment you are running (e.g. if the machines are managed by enterprise management system). As for the other option, you can use a public CA for the broker certificate and user username/password to authenticate the client.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try both options and see which one suits the system.